# Namespace of IService not found

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wcf-security

I'm trying to implement authorization into an existing WCF-service.
To do that I following a [Microsoft Pattern & practices tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649647.aspx#Step5).

At Step 5, the service class should derive from `IService`, however my existing service class does not and when I add `: IService` to my class Visual Studio doesn't recognize it.

**How can I derive from the interface as described in the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649647.aspx#Step5)?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace MyCompanyNamespace.API.IISServiceHost
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class CompanyNameAPIService : IService //not recognized!
    {
        public ApproveitAPIService()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plz check the namespace once. is the namespace where IService is in has been referenced?

Comment: @NewtonSheikh. i don't know. I have no idea in which namespace I can find the interface "IService".

Comment: What IDE are you using? If it is Visual Studio, right click on IService and see if the resolve option is there.

Comment: IService is the standard interface when you create a new WCF service. Check your code and see if there is something like an `ICompanyNameAPIService`.

Comment: Have you checked that your interface definition is public?  If it's not set explicitly to public then you won't be able to inherit from it.

Comment: @Koen. Could it be that I don't need to implement that interface? I'm just following the article so I don't actually know why I should make my class derive from that interface.

Comment: If you want to use WCF functionality then you need to create an interface to provide the methods you wish to expose.

Comment: Can you find a class anywhere in your code called IService.cs?  Looking at the tutorial it should be created when you create the WCF service.

Comment: As @Andrew stated in his comment: you need to provide an interface when exposing things through WCF. Since this was an existing WCF service, it should have been there before.

Comment: @Andrew - technically, you do **not** have to create an interface to provide the methods for a WCF service.  You can do it all in a class without an interface.  Best practice is to use an interface, however.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view you have to Implement `IService` by yourself like in this [Microsoft-Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx).